# Use socket.get when disconnect event is fired

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm making a little game. When an client disconnects, I want the others clients to get notified, so that they delete the user in the client-side.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    socket.get('player', function (error, player) {
        console.log(player.pseudo + ' is now disconnected.');
        socket.broadcast.emit('removePlayer', player.pseudo);
    });
});
```

Sometimes, I get this error:

```
            console.log(player.pseudo + ' is now disconnected.');
                              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pseudo' of null
```

Is it because `player` is already removed ? Is it another way to get a player's username ?

Edit:
Oh I got it. The bug appened when the user hadn't sent its pseudo. So, obviously `player.pseudo` wasn't set. Now I check first if the player is known.

```
socket.on('disconnect', function (disconnect) {
    socket.get('player', function (error, player) {
        if (player) {
            console.log(player.pseudo + ' is now disconnected.');
            socket.broadcast.emit('removePlayer', player.pseudo);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the `error` variable for any errors?

Comment: irrelevant to question but important - It will be more good if you make use of getter and setter of socket object itself.

Comment: @Pranav You're very welcome for that :-)
Can you give me an example ? I already use the getter (`socket.get`) and the setter of the socket object, don't I ?

Comment: yup, it was about setting the value only. You did it correctly for get. I did overlook mistakenly, apologies.